# R - determine if values in 2 different columns are at least a 95% match

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider this example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Client = c('Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3', 'Client4', 'Client5'),
         'Home Address' = c('123 N. Franklin Ave.', '345 Circle Drive', '567 Smith St. Suite 5', '678 Buchanan Rd. SW', '12 State Street'),
         'Mail Address' = c('123 Franklin Avenue', '345 S. Circle Dr.', '567 Smith Street Ste 5', '678 Buchanan Road', '17 Ralph Lane'))
```

If you look closely at the address related columns, they're all basically (with the exception of one) and the only differences are really the direction or street abbreviation being included or excluded. What I'd like to do is a comparison between the two to determine if there is at least a 95% match between the two address columns.

So an example result would be an additional column to the df stating 'Yes' or 'No'.

How can this be done?

Comment: How exactly do you define a "95%" match? There are a number of ways to do fuzzy comparison using the [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf) package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the Jaro-Winkler Distance, which uses the number of matching characters within a certain "window", transpositions, and length of the two strings to compute a similarity score. Strings that have matching characters at the start are weighted more heavily (`p`).

```
library(stringdist)

df |>
    dplyr::mutate(jw = stringsim(`Home Address`, `Mail Address`, method = "jw", p = .1))
```

You can use this `jw` column to create a cutoff for your data.

**Output**

```
  Client  `Home Address`        `Mail Address`            jw
  <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>                  <dbl>
1 Client1 123 N. Franklin Ave.  123 Franklin Avenue    0.872
2 Client2 345 Circle Drive      345 S. Circle Dr.      0.862
3 Client3 567 Smith St. Suite 5 567 Smith Street Ste 5 0.913
4 Client4 678 Buchanan Rd. SW   678 Buchanan Road      0.934
5 Client5 12 State Street       17 Ralph Lane          0.555
```